# Main industrial method for producing ethyl ethanoate (acetate)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, process-chemistry

I am aware there are various methods, however, which is most prevalent in industry? Researching on Google has indicated Fischer esterification or Tishchenko reaction and other versions. Which is most common?

Comment: This source (though 10 yrs old)  says it is the condensation of ethanol and acetic acid with cat. cH2SO4  https://www.icis.com/explore/resources/news/2007/11/02/9075322/ethyl-acetate-production-and-manufacturing-process/  The Avada process which makes it from ethlyene and acetic acid is also significant

Answer (score 2):

According to [ACS Molecule of the Week](https://www.acs.org/content/acs/en/molecule-of-the-week/archive/e/ethyl-acetate.html):

> As you might expect, ethyl acetate was first synthesized from ethanol and acetic acid. The reaction was the classic acid-catalyzed Fischer esterification, which dates back to 1895. This is still the most widely used commercial synthesis. An alternative method is the Tishchenko reaction in which acetaldehyde disproportionates in the presence of base to the alcohol and the acid that then esterify *in situ*.

The mechanism of  Tishchenko reaction is depicted in following diagram where $\ce{R = CH3}$:

[image: Mechanism of the Tishchenko Reaction]